# Can Servicestack.Interfaces dll be used without license?

Tags: servicestack

I am assuming so as it is downloaded with the ServiceStack.Client nuget package which does not need a license.  I'm looking to build whitelabel apps which connect to a central servicestack based API, hence I want to reference ServiceStack.Client and ServiceStack.Interfaces in various projects & solutions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it can since `ServiceStack.Interfaces` is only a definition library and is not limited by any of the [built-in free quotas](https://servicestack.net/download#free-quotas).